# Pandas sorting strings in cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
individual  states
1           Alaska, Hawaii 
2           Hawaii, Alaska
3           Kansas, Iowa, Maryland
4           New Jersey, Newada
5           Newada, New Jersey
```

I would like to sort the strings within the cells and would like to obtain the following dataframe

```
individual  states
1           Alaska, Hawaii 
2           Alaska, Hawaii
3           Iowa, Kansas, Maryland
4           New Jersey, Newada
5           New Jersey, Newada
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a simple problem... I would suggest splitting, sorting and joining with `map`:

```
df['states'] = df['states'].map(lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(x.split(', '))))
df

   individual                  states
0           1          Alaska, Hawaii
1           2          Alaska, Hawaii
2           3  Iowa, Kansas, Maryland
3           4      New Jersey, Newada
4           5      New Jersey, Newada
```

Comment: Alright, I actually thought there was a simpler solution to this

Comment: @edyvedy13 It would depend on your definition of simple... but this would be the simplest one imo.

Comment: Definately, it is simple. I just thought I was missing something very trivial :)

Answer (score 4):

I am using `get_dummies` then `dot` back the result

```
s = df.states.str.get_dummies(', ')
s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
Out[861]: 
0           Alaska,Hawaii
1           Alaska,Hawaii
2    Iowa,Kansas,Maryland
3       New Jersey,Newada
4       New Jersey,Newada
dtype: object

df['state'] = s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
```